# Passing delegates with unknown parameter list

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, func

I have a requirement for a validator class to run a series of validation methods which each return a error code. Depending on the severity of the error, I may want to abort the rest of the validations. I could check the returned error code after each call and not perform the remaining validations but this would add a lot of duplicated clutter to the main 'driving' routine.

So, I wrote the following helper routine that handles this for me...

```
public IList<Error> ValidateSet(InputType input,
    params Func<InputType, IList<Error>>[] validations)
{
    var errors = new List<Error>();

    foreach (var validation in validations)
    {
        errors.AddRange(validation(input));

        if (AbortValidations(errors))
            break;
    }

    return errors;
}
```

This is called as per below and works great...

```
var errors = new List<Error>();

errors.AddRange(
    ValidateSet(input,
        ValidateX,
        ValidateY,
        ValidateZ)
);
```

The problem I have now is that some validations require additional parameters other than one parameter of InputType.

Is there any way I could keep this same useful structure? Note that I can't simply pass in the results of each validation as I don't want to run the remaining validations if an earlier one returns an 'abort' error code (the validations load data so this is a performance requirement).

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you know the additional parameters at the time of calling `ValidateSet()`, if so then you can wrap the actual call in a lambda function.

Comment: Cicada - Correct, I've now accepted 3 out of the grand total of four  questions I've asked :) Steve - thanks that looks promising. I'll investigate to see if that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the additional parameters at the time of calling `ValidateSet()` then you can do something like the following

```
ValidateSet(
    input,
    input_type => ValidateX(input_type, additional_param1),
    input_type => ValidateY(input_type, something2),
    ValidateZ
);
```

Comment: Steve, what would the signature of ValidateSet be changed to for this to work? I think I understand what you are saying, just a little foggy about the details...

Comment: No the signature for ValidateSet is still the same. All that is happening is that the calls to ValidateX and ValidateY are being wrapped in another function which has a signature matching the one that ValidateSet expects. [Here's a link that kind of explains it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Steve. That makes sense after thinking about it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what these other arguments are but perhaps a struct

```
struct
{
  public InputType  Input {get;set;}
  public int OtherArgument {get;set;}
}
```

so your one argument input becomes a bucket of arguments one of which is input

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the answer. I did consider something like this but the second parameter is optional and it's type may vary. I also considered using generics i.e. ValidateSet<T, U> where U is the second parameter type. This is closer but only some of the validation methods will require a parameter of type U

Comment: That would pretty much count it out @Steve answer proably best if you need that sort of flexibility. Didn't want to offer the Object[] alternative. :(